# What do these 15 apple mach o linker error means

Tags: ios, linker-errors

[image: A lot of errors here...]

And this:

```
Ld /Users/davidraijmakers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scanner-bbwbbvayxxnrhwdsgbkvibplofyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Scanner.app/Scanner normal armv7
    cd /Users/davidraijmakers/Documents/xcodezooi/Scanner
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/davidraijmakers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scanner-bbwbbvayxxnrhwdsgbkvibplofyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/davidraijmakers/Documents/xcodezooi/Scanner/Scanner/ScanditSDK -F/Users/davidraijmakers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scanner-bbwbbvayxxnrhwdsgbkvibplofyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/davidraijmakers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scanner-bbwbbvayxxnrhwdsgbkvibplofyw/Build/Intermediates/Scanner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Scanner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Scanner.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -liconv -lz -framework CoreVideo -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5 -o /Users/davidraijmakers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scanner-bbwbbvayxxnrhwdsgbkvibplofyw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Scanner.app/Scanner

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1486 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1602 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1655 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      l1241 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      l1670 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1671 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1672 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1673 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1674 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1675 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1676 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      ...
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version>*, std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version> > > >, zxing::Ref<zxing::datamatrix::Version> const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::datamatrix::ECB*, std::allocator<zxing::datamatrix::ECB*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::datamatrix::ECB**, std::vector<zxing::datamatrix::ECB*, std::allocator<zxing::datamatrix::ECB*> > >, zxing::datamatrix::ECB* const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion>*, std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion> > > >, zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::QRCodeVersion> const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::qrcode::ECB*, std::allocator<zxing::qrcode::ECB*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::qrcode::ECB**, std::vector<zxing::qrcode::ECB*, std::allocator<zxing::qrcode::ECB*> > >, zxing::qrcode::ECB* const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask>*, std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask> > > >, zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::DataMask> const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern*, std::allocator<zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern**, std::vector<zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern*, std::allocator<zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern*> > >, zxing::qrcode::AlignmentPattern* const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern>*, std::vector<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern>, std::allocator<zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern> > > >, zxing::Ref<zxing::qrcode::FinderPattern> const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      ...
  "std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      l1598 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      l1604 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      l1481 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1482 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1483 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1484 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1485 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      l1243 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1244 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1245 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1477 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1480 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1602 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1655 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      l1670 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1671 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1672 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1673 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1674 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1675 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1676 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const", referenced from:
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1480 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1602 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1655 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      l1378 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      zxing::Exception::Exception(zxing::Exception const&) in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()", referenced from:
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1480 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1602 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1655 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      l1348 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1481 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1482 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1483 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1585 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1600 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      l1602 in libscanditsdk-iphone-2.2.5.a(mirasense.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Maybe something with armv7. How do i set this correctly. Works fine on the simulator

Comment: Which device and which version of xcode are you using

Comment: are you using another project within yours?

Comment: I am using an SDK yes. the ScanditSDK version 2.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This likely has to do with XCode not using the right C++ standard library. To fix this, click on your project, go to the project's target under Build Settings, search for the setting called "C++ Standard Library". Set it to either libstdc++ or Compiler Default, it should not be set to libc++.

You need to do this because the Scandit SDK does currently not yet run with the new C++ 11 standard library that was recently introduced into XCode. In the not so far future releases will be compiled with a C++ 11 compiler and run with the std library now set as default in XCode.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this recently with version 3.0.0-RC1 of the Scandit SDK. For me, the problem came from not linking to the libc++.dylib library. (Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries)

Comment: Adding libc++.dylib in libraries reduced some error...Instead by adding libstdc++.dylib removed all errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking against the C++ standard library. Compile your code as C++ (or Objective-C++ if you need it) and the linker will automatically incorporate that library.

Comment: @H2C03 Thanks for your quick reply, but How do i do this?